# SQL Server 2014 sporadic poor query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have sporadic poor query performance of the same query with just a different parameter and we do not know why this is happening.

Maybe someone has an idea how this can happen.

We are running the same query thousands of times a day and somehow a few times the query runs 400ms instead of 1ms.

I created a trace-file to get some information which exact query is causing the problems and found this in the trace log:

```
exec sp_executesql 
           N'SELECT A.* 
             FROM Teile A 
             WHERE (A.Barcode = @P1)  
             ORDER BY A.Barcode ASC, A.ID ASC 
             OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY', 
           N'@P1 char(26)','1022669459                '
```

This query starts at 15:24:03.250 and stops at 15:24:03.650 => duration 400ms.

During the execution the query

```
exec sp_executesql 
           N'SELECT A.* 
             FROM Teile A 
             WHERE (A.Barcode = @P1)  
             ORDER BY A.Barcode ASC, A.ID ASC 
             OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY', 
           N'@P1 char(26)','1015092284                '
```

starts at 15:24:03.450 and stops at 15:24:03.451 => duration 1ms.

Has anybody an idea why the same query with just a different parameter is executing very slow and another as the average in 1ms?

I tried the first query in the smss but there I always get a execution time of 1ms, too. So it seems to me the server sometimes needs more time to execute the query, but I do not know why and have no idea to found out why.

Every help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Markus

Comment: Any chance the table is being updated during the day causing the 400ms queries due to the lock during the insert/update transaction? Otherwise, I'd consider adding `NOLOCK` to prevent impact of shared locks or otherwise.

Comment: Locking? Server load? Network latency? The french? Take your pick. This isn't something that can be answered in a Q+A format. You will need to do some investigation.

Comment: A lot of reasons. Initial investigation should be the following: 1) Check CPU vs. Duration in the trace. If CPU is lower than Duration your query might be waited for something (maybe for a lock), if they are pretty the same, you might get different query plans, check that plans. These are the most obvious reasons which should be checked first of all. After that - go deeper by yourself of hire a consultant.

Comment: the data you are reading might usually be cached in RAM, sometimes this may not be the case - is just one theory - you could clear sql memory caches (google), then see if it goes to the slower 400ms

Comment: Is there a significant difference in the number of rows selected based upon the parameters? This could be a parameter sniffing and plan caching issue

Comment: Have you checked indexes defrag, from page splitting.  Are the statistics been updated and how often

Comment: @JasonW why proposing nolock? you never want dirty read! you dont know if the data is being updated or obsolete or delete or else! never use nolock unless you know that the data might be bad

Comment: Only meant nolock if data is not changing over course of day. Agreed if data is changing. Sorry wasn't clear @fredou.

Comment: @all: Thank you for your comments! I guess there is no LOCK problem as the data is not been edited that often and I can´t see any update-statement in the trace-file. Which is the best way to check any locks on that table? Furthermore the other statment is much faster even it is running at the same time. The CPU in the trace is 6ms and the duration is 400ms. So no different query-plans I guess. As both query will always delivery one row this can´t be a parameter sniffing problem, right? I will check index defrag and update statistics. Any other advices?

Comment: I did some further investigation and none of the mentioned points lead me to the problem :( @JasonW: I found a aquire-lock for the select-statement when the select-statement starts and a release-lock when the select-statement finishs. So no LOCk-Problems here.

Comment: @AndrewDeighton: The server was restarted this morning and so the chache was filled up again and this did not help. A slow query runs as fast as suggested a few minutes later in the smss when I anlayze it.

Comment: @mvisser: I checked the statistics and they weren´t updated the last 2 weeks and I did that manually but it did not help. Fragmentation is 50% and I will rebuild it. But shouldn´t be all the queries be much slower instead of a few queries?

Comment: Not necessary. It all depends the amount of data. First of all its not good that statistics was last updated 2 weeks ago, very much a cause of High CPU/ DIsk IO.  But ok, you updated the statistics and still not helping. Then yes Index Fragmentation can be the problem.  So a quick fix is to re-organize an index(you can do it manually and in emergency can be done on production.  The Index will still be online). But if the Fragmentation is over 70%(Some DBAs will say 30%) then you need Rebuild the index. (This needs to be done during the maintenance window).

Comment: If you dont have Maintenance task, I have a script that will defrag Indexes. But if you do you. My advice would have a task every night to reorganise Indexes and then after that Update Statistics.  Then once a week Build all the indexes over a certain fragmentation.  But that can also depend on how badly the Indexes get Fragmented.

Comment: Also if your Indexes gets fragmented a lot quickly.  Then I will advise to have a FILL FACTOR on the Indexes. This will improve fragmentation by 90%. But it can be expensive on Disk space

Comment: @mvisser: Thank you for your advices. I will create a task to rebuild all the indexes and the statistics. Hope that will help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like parameter sniffing or bad statistics.
Try following: 
1.Update statistics for the table
2.Add "OPTION (RECOMPILE)" to the end of the query
3.Add "OPTION (OPTIMIZE for UNKNOWN)" to the end of the query

Comment: Yes I like OPTION(RECOMPILE). But you dont want to RECOMPILE the SP all the time. if its parameter sniffing then create a new set of parameters assign the original parameters with the new ones.  Then in that case you are for certain that there is no parameter sniffing

Comment: It depends. If SP runs infrequently it might be OK. Why you do not like to update statistics? BTW: I'd suggest change BarCode to INT or BIGINT, or at least to VARCHAR. Also, see Denis Reznik's response. Sorting by Barcode is useless if you extract only one; Use "TOP 1" - it looks simpler.